# Uploading File - PHP MySQL

Tags: php, html, mysql, css, blob

I am building a web based database that allows users to upload a profile picture to their account, if they choose not to add a photo I want the default image to display instead of the empty image tag. For some reason if no file is selected, the blob in MySQL gets populated anyway, with I don't know what. Is there something I need to change within the database or a piece of code I need to add in??

Code for entering in the data:

```
$username = mysql_prep($_POST["username"]);
        $password = password_encrypt($_POST["password"]);
//        $confirm = password_encrypt($_POST["confirm"]);
        $firstName = mysql_prep($_POST["firstName"]);
        $lastName = mysql_prep($_POST["lastName"]);
        $File = $_FILES['fileField']['name'];
        $tempnum = rand(20, 980780980);
        $newfile = $tempnum . $File;

//        if("password" != "confirm") {
//            $_SESSION["message"] = "ERROR: Passwords must match.";
//        }else{
            if (file_exists("images/profile_pictures/" . $newfile)) {
                echo $newfile . " already exists. ";
            } else {
                $query = "INSERT INTO users (";
                $query .= "  username, password, firstName, lastName, image";
                $query .= ") VALUES (";
                $query .= "  '{$username}', '{$password}', '{$firstName}', '{$lastName}', '{$newfile}'";
                $query .= ")";
                $result = mysqli_query($connection, $query);
                copy($_FILES['fileField']['tmp_name'], 'images/profile_pictures/' . $newfile);
                if ($result > 0) {
                    // Success
                    $_SESSION["message"] = "User created.";
                    redirect_to("add_user.php");
                } else {
                    // Failure
                    $_SESSION["message"] = "User creation failed.";
                }
            }
        }
//    }
}
<form id="form1" name="form1" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="add_user.php">
                <h2>Create New User</h2>
                <p>
                    <label for="fname">First Name:</label>
                    <input id="fname" type="text" class="textbox" name="firstName" value="" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label>
                    <input id="lname" type="text" class="textbox" name="lastName" value="" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="uname">Username:</label>
                    <input id="uname" type="text" class="textbox" name="username" value="" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="pword">Password:</label>
                    <input id="pword" type="password" class="textbox" name="password" value="" />
                </p>
                <p>
                    <label for="pword">Confirm Password:</label>
                    <input id="pword" type="password" class="textbox" name="confirm" value="" />
                </p>
<!--                <p>-->
<!--                    <label for="profile">Profile Picture:-->
<!--                    <input id="fileField" type="file" name="fileField"></label>-->
<!--                </p>-->
                <input type="submit" class="button" name="submit" value="Add User" onclick="return confirm('Do you wish to add a new user?');"/>
                <p><a href="manage_users.php" class="link">Cancel</a></p>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Code for displaying data:

```
<table id="users">
                <tr>
                    <th style="text-align: left; width: 75px;">Image</th>
                    <th style="text-align: left; width: 150px;">First Name</th>
                    <th style="text-align: left; width: 150px;">Last Name</th>
                    <th style="text-align: left; width: 150px;">Username</th>
                    <th style="text-align: left; width: 35px;">Actions</th>
                </tr>
                <?php while($user = mysqli_fetch_assoc($user_set)) { ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                        <?php

                            if($user["image"] == ""){
                            echo "<img id='profilepic' src='images/profile_pictures/default.gif' alt='Default Profile Pic'>";
                            } else{
                            echo "<img id='profilepic' src='images/profile_pictures/".$user['image']."' />";
                            }?>
                        </td>
                        <!--htmlentities converts all applicable characters to html entities-->
                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($user["firstName"]); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($user["lastName"]); ?></td>
                        <td><?php echo htmlentities($user["username"]); ?></td>
                        <td style="text-align: center;"><a href="edit_users.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($user["userId"]); ?>">
                                <img id="icon" src="images/edit.png" alt="Edit Icon"></a>
                        <a href="delete_user.php?id=<?php echo urlencode($user["userId"]); ?>" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?');">
                            <img id="icon" src="images/delete.png" alt="Delete Icon"></a></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php } ?>
            </table>
```

Comment: You might want to store the location of the image instead of the image itself in the database. In theory check if image is uploaded, if not store the location of defualt pic in the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using NULL instead of `if($user["image"] == "")`  in your code for displaying data?

Try this: `if(!$user["image"])`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, I've tried that but it's as if something is going into the database even though nothing has been selected? So it's not actually null.

Comment: Then invert the code :)
Try putting the 'if' part in the form, so that when the user doesn't use an image he gets the default one.
When you need to display it, it doesn't matter anymore wheter it is the default or a customed one. You just pick the info in your database.